# MySQL PDO won't work with integers

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I Have a basic function that looks like this:

```
public function query($query, $params = []) {
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($query);

        // Bind parameters based on value's type
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if(is_int($value)) {
                $statement->bindParam($key + 1, $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            } else {
                $statement->bindParam($key + 1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            }
        }

        $statement->execute();

        return $statement;
}
```

For whatever reason, when I run something like this:

```
public static function photosByTag($tag, $user = null) {
    $db = new DBConnection();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM photos JOIN tags ON tags.photo = photos.pid WHERE tag LIKE ? AND owner = ?";
    $params = [$tag, $user];

    $result = $db->query($query, $params);
    return $result->fetchAll();
}

photosByTag('city', 1)
```

It doesn't work. If I replace the `AND owner = ?` with `AND owner = 1` it works fine. Something is wrong when binding integers as params, but I don't know what or why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't the bind, it is the loop. If you look at the manual, the second parameter for bindParam (&$variable) requires a reference. Your loop destroys that reference once it reassigns $value.  The solution would be to use `$params[$key]` instead of `$value` in the `bindParam()`

---

Seems kind of redundant to do it this way when you can just use the `execute()` statement to bind the parameters.

```
$statement->execute($params);
```

Just let PDO handle how it assigns the variables.  All your doing is checking what is submitted and then choosing the type, you're not enforcing a type, so it is probably similar to what PDO::execute does as is.

Comment: This is what I use to do. This doesn't work though when using `LIMIT` because execute() passes all values in as a string, and MySQL requires the `LIMIT` to be an int. `LIMIT 5` works, while `LIMIT '5'` will not.

Comment: If you provide an integer, I would think PDO would pass it as an integer, but I don't see of many reasons why you would need to bind a limit number.  If the limit is provided by user input, then you can just use `intval()` in the query.  You don't normally need protection from integers.

Comment: From PHP's docs on `PDOStatement::execute`: "An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. **All values are treated as PDO::PARAM_STR**." And it isn't for user input, but for function parameters. A possible example, `getMostPopular(5)` will return the most popular items, limited to 5.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reference.  So in your query do... `$query = "SELECT .... LIMIT ".intval($int);`  You don't need to bind it.

Comment: While this is likely an option, it seems like a poor choice, nor does it address whatever the actual problem with the above is (which as far as I can tell, looks like it should work). I try not to do any direct string interpolation in sql queries.

Comment: Well, I think it allows for you to rid yourself of the redundant code.  Parameter binding is normally used for field values, not expressions.  As for the above code, have you verified whether is_int is true or false (which bindParam is running).

Comment: Yeah, I verified `is_int()` is returning the expected values. Interestingly, the above doesn't work even if I run it as `photosByTag('city', '1')`, which does work in MySQL, which does the type conversion itself. Also works if I replace the actual query with `AND owner = '1'`.

Comment: What is the PDO error mode?  Is it still set to silent?  Make sure you turn that on, maybe there is another issue you are overlooking.

Comment: There is no error returned. Though there are errors for more complicated queries, this is just the simplest example. The others are side effects of this (foreign key errors). And @EternalHour, I'm not sure I follow what you're asking.

Comment: If you do a `var_dump` on `$params` after the foreach, is `$user` still `INT` before the `execute`?

Comment: Oh, yes it is. `$params` looks like what you would expect. The problem only seems to be when binding. If I pass it in as a hardcoded value in the query (`1` or `'1'`) it works. At this rate I'll probably just do what @Devon mentioned above. Though hopefully this is figured out.

Comment: @LucasRaines, does the above query work if you remove the first parameter?  Only bind owner?

Comment: I believe I know the problem, the problem isn't the bind, it is the loop.  If you look at the manual, the second parameter for bindParam (`&$variable`) requires a reference.  Your loop destroys that reference once it reassigns `$value`.

Comment: @Devon, what you're saying makes sense. If I only bind owner, it does work. So it does seem to be a problem with more than 1 binding.

Comment: Yes, so you can use `$params[$key]` instead of `$value` since that reference would still exist.

Comment: It works! All this time and it was a problem with the loop. Nice catch on the `&$variable`. Thanks a lot.